# Counting items that have a matching attribute

Tags: java, performance, join

Here is my code which is going to through multiple `for` loops to get the matching product attribute.

I have single product with attributes trying to find out the matching product with same attribute value from a list of Product. I am having a multiple for loop. Can anyone suggest a way to optimize this solution?

```
// This is my single product which is empty with listOf attributes
// (Example : brand, size, color etc.)
Product singleProduct = new Product().setAttrs(
    new ArrayList<ProductAttribute>());

int productFound = 0;

// Get List of product from respose object
List<Product> products = response.getProductList();
for (Product product : products) {
    for (ProductAttribute proAttr : product.getAttrs()) {
        for (ProductAttribute singleProdAttr : singleProduct.getAttrs()) {
            if (proAttr.getValue().equals(singleProdAttr.getValue())) {
                productFound++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would use Hashmaps and look up the values.

Comment: As we all want to make our code more efficient or improve it in one way or another, **try to write a title that summarizes what your code does**, not what you want to get out of a review. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review - Asking Questions](http://meta.CodeReview.StackExchange.com/a/2438/41243) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Comment: I wanted to comment but there are a few questions: 1. Please share the code of Product  and ProductAttribute class. 2. Do you intend to find a product from list of products that match singleProduct with all attributes equal or any attribute is equal?